# Detect Collision with arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, collision

Ok, so I want to build a method to detect if two objects are colliding. Their hitboxes are stored in arrays. Like this [topLeftX, topLeftY, bottomRightX, bottomRightY] for each of the two objects. I can't figure out the right if statements to use the two arrays to detect this.

```
public class Physics {
    public static boolean isColliding(int ob1Hitbox[], int ob2Hitbox[]) {

    }
}
```

The method must returns true if collision has occured.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What does `objects` means here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Rectangle#intersects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects-java.awt.Rectangle-) in order to have the calculation done for you:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Physics {
    public static boolean isColliding(int[] ob1Hitbox, int[] ob2Hitbox) {
        return toRectangle(ob1Hitbox).intersects(toRectangle(ob2Hitbox));
    }

    private static Rectangle toRectangle(int[] hitbox) {
        int x = hitbox[0];
        int y = hitbox[1];
        int width = hitbox[2] - x;
        int height = y - hitbox[3];
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the word `static`? Different physics may exist in a parallel universe ;)